# Electric Guitar issue

Tags: electric-guitar

I have an EVH USA guitar. Issue....sound still comes from amp when volume pot on guitar is at 0. Additionally, sound is cutting on and off with volume pot at 10. Could this be a guitar issue or amp issue?

Comment: Since twiddling the volume pot precipitates the problem it's way more likely to be guitar than amp.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim. I was really hoping it is the guitar as opposed to the amp. Just purchased Line 6 rig three months ago.

Comment: Maybe you should be hoping it's the amp. At least that's under guarantee..! But the pot change is easy and cheap!

Comment: I thought a main selling point of EVH guitars was the high quality pots, for making swells like he does in Cathedral and other solos.  Strange.

Comment: For future reference, those of us with ordinary guitars were usually taught to "never use the pots", leave them on 10 and get a volume pedal.  Many guitars (even expensive high end guitars) have cheap pots that will break or seize up after a few hundred or thousand turns.  Controlling tone and volume from foot pedals saves them.  Just one point of view.

Answer (score 6):

It's *volume pot* for *potentiometer*, not volume pod, and it is probably a bad pot. You could try spraying some switch-cleaning fluid into the pot to see if that helps; failing that, replace the pot.

If you aren't comfortable opening up the guitar to work on it, take it to a good tech. If the guitar is newish, take it back to the store where you bought it to see if they will rectify the issue (possibly without charge).

Comment: Thanks for the response David Bowling. I was hoping to hear that. My Line 6 rig is three months old.

Answer (score 2):

I could also be that the pot is loose and turns in the guitar body so that the wires are getting crossed and shorting out.  With any guitar that you own, if you start to notice that a volume or tone knob does not stop hard at either end of its range, you should inspect the locking nut to make sure it is tightly secure.

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is a bad potentiometer. It is a ring type potentiometer that has its limiter shifted towards max (possibly forced past max). Thus the knob stops before it reaches zero and gets past max.
It must be replaced. You could repair the potentiometer by disassembly, but the chances are most likely you won't be able to fix it. 
Better have it replaced.